# How do i make this code more compact? (python)

Tags: python

```
birth_year = int(input("What year were you born: "))
current_year = int(input("What year is it: "))
name = input("What is your name: ")
age = current_year-birth_year
print("Your name is", name , "and you are", age , "years old.")
```

#asks for your birth year, current year and your name then it calculates your age and prints your age and name

Comment: Why do you want to make it more "compact"?

Comment: I agree, the question is 'Why'. But this is part of 'How' : `age `  is a temporary

Comment: The code isn't correct, If you were born on 17th dec 2000, then you wouldn't be 21 yet

Comment: You can remove the white spaces around the operators. That’ll make the code harder to read but you’ll save some characters.

Answer (score 1):

Code is fine! But if you want to improve it I would recommend one thing - don't ask about current year as it can be easily taken using [datetime](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime) module

```
from datetime import date

current_year = date.today().year
```

Answer (score -2):

While

```py
print("Your name is", input("What is your name: "), "and you are", int(input("What year is it: ")) - int(input("What year were you born: ")), "years old.")
```

would be more compact, it's no longer easy to read. It's better to leave it the way it is now.

Edit: You should consider calculating not only the year but also the date. You might want to have a look at the python datetime module.

Comment: If the op knows how to use variables, I'm pretty sure they'd know how they could write it without using them.